# Как нарисовать простую карту в OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, графика, карты, openstreetmap

С помощью [libosmium](https://osmcode.org/libosmium/) я загрузил карту, и достал из неё водоёмы.
У меня есть массив вида

```
614879291:551879409; 614880288:551870745; 614883306:551866963; 614884798:551865497; 614884826:551864871; 614884138:551863174; 614882791:551862009; 614880428:551852906; 614879853:551844234; 614879730:551842378; 614879776:551841969; 614881010:551831052;
```

в котором хранятся координаты границ водоёма.
Проблема в том, что 1. координаты - очень "большие" числа(может быть это не проблема?), и 2. координаты очень близки и когда я их пытаюсь нарисовать, получается, что все они находятся в одной точки

Вот мой код:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

// For the location index. There are different types of indexes available.
// This will work for all input files keeping the index in memory.
#include <osmium/index/map/flex_mem.hpp>
// For the NodeLocationForWays handler
#include <osmium/handler/node_locations_for_ways.hpp>
// The type of index used. This must match the include file above
using index_type = osmium::index::map::FlexMem<osmium::unsigned_object_id_type, osmium::Location>;
// The location handler always depends on the index type
using location_handler_type = osmium::handler::NodeLocationsForWays<index_type>;
// For assembling multipolygons
#include <osmium/area/assembler.hpp>
#include <osmium/area/multipolygon_manager.hpp>
// Allow any format of input files (XML, PBF, ...)
#include <osmium/io/any_input.hpp>
// For osmium::geom::Coordinates
#include <osmium/geom/coordinates.hpp>
#include <osmium/geom/projection.hpp>
#include "GL/glut.h"

int WinWidth = 640;
int WinHeight = 480;

float zPos = -250;

struct Cords {
    Cords(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    int x = 0, y = 0;
};

std::vector<Cords> lake;

class WaterHandler : public osmium::handler::Handler {

    void print_water(const char *type, const char *name, const osmium::geom::Coordinates &c) {
        std::printf("%8.4f,%8.4f %-15s %s\n", c.x, c.y, type, name ? name : "");
    }

    osmium::geom::Coordinates calc_center(const osmium::NodeRefList &nr_list) {
        osmium::geom::Coordinates c{0.0, 0.0};

        for (const auto &nr : nr_list) {
            c.x += nr.lon();
            c.y += nr.lat();
        }

        c.x /= nr_list.size();
        c.y /= nr_list.size();

        return c;
    }

public:
    void area(const osmium::Area &area) {
        const char *water = area.tags()["water"];
        if (water) {
            const auto center = calc_center(*area.cbegin<osmium::OuterRing>());
            for (const auto &nr : *area.cbegin<osmium::OuterRing>()) {
                std::cout << nr.x() << ":" << nr.y() << "; ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            print_water(water, area.tags()["name"], center);

            if (lake.empty()) {
                for (const auto &nr : *area.cbegin<osmium::OuterRing>()) {
                    lake.emplace_back(nr.x(), nr.y());
                }
                glutMainLoop();
            }
        }
    }

}; // class WaterHandler

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0, 0, zPos);

    glRotatef(90, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glScalef(1, 1, 1);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glColor4f(0, 0, 1, 0.1);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3d(-60, 0, -70);
    glVertex3d(60, 0, -70);
    glVertex3d(60, 0, 70);
    glVertex3d(-60, 0, 70);
    glEnd();

    glColor4f(0, 0, 1, 1);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_POINTS);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (const Cords &c : lake) {
        glVertex3f(c.x, 0, c.y);
    }
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h) {
    if (w == 0 || h == 0) return;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(40.0, w / h, 0.5, 5000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    WinWidth = w;
    WinHeight = h;
}


void mouse(int btn, int state, int x, int y) {
    if(btn == 3) { // Scroll down
        zPos += 0.1;
    } else if(btn == 4) { // Scroll up
        zPos -= 0.1;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(WinWidth, WinHeight);

    glutCreateWindow("Test");
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_POINTS);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1.0);
    glOrtho(-WinWidth, WinWidth, WinHeight, -WinHeight, 100, -100);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);


    const osmium::io::File input_file{"input.osm.pbf"};

    osmium::area::Assembler::config_type assembler_config;
    assembler_config.create_empty_areas = false;

    osmium::area::MultipolygonManager<osmium::area::Assembler> mp_manager{assembler_config};

    std::cout << "Pass 1..." << std::endl;
    osmium::relations::read_relations(input_file, mp_manager);
    std::cout << "Pass 1 done" << std::endl;

    index_type index;

    location_handler_type location_handler{index};
    location_handler.ignore_errors();

    WaterHandler data_handler;

    std::cout << "Pass 2..." << std::endl;
    osmium::io::Reader reader{input_file, osmium::io::read_meta::no};

    osmium::apply(reader, location_handler, data_handler,
                  mp_manager.handler([&data_handler](const osmium::memory::Buffer &area_buffer) {
                      osmium::apply(area_buffer, data_handler);
                  }));

    reader.close();
    std::cout << "Pass 2 done" << std::endl;
}
```

Я видел проекты для рисования карт, типа [mapnik](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik), или [mapbox](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native), но не смог разобраться в их коде.

C OpenGL, я работаю недавно, поэтому, возможно я делаю что-то глупое. Помогите, пожалуйста править этот код или хотя-бы подскажите, в каком направлении двигаться.